# Check if an arbitrary user is in Administrator Group with Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, admin, ctypes

Is there a way to check if any given user is in the Administrator's Group?

I know how to check if the *current* user is an admin using:

```
import ctypes
print ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
```

However if I'm logged in as userA, I want to know if userZed has admin privileges.

Any pointers or suggestions would help, it seems I can't track down any documentation on ctypes.windll.shell32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a website with code to do this:

http://skippylovesmalorie.wordpress.com/tag/python-windows/

I tested it and it works. Can be used as follows, note that the strings **HAVE** to be unicode or the login will fail:

Python 2.7:

```
print(user_is_admin(u"johndoe", u"password123", u"MYDOMAIN"))
```

Python 3.x:

```
print(user_is_admin("johndoe", "password123", "MYDOMAIN"))
```

Here's the code, for future reference:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes

def current_user_is_admin():
    return user_token_is_admin(0)

def user_is_admin(username, password, domain=None):
    """note that username, password, and domain should all be unicode"""

    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0
    token = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE()
    if ctypes.windll.advapi32.LogonUserW(username, domain, password,
            LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ctypes.byref(token)) == 0:
        raise Exception("user logon failed")

    try:
        return user_token_is_admin(token)
    finally:
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(token)


def user_token_is_admin(user_token):
    """
    using the win32 api, determine if the user with token user_token has administrator rights
    """
    class SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("byte0", ctypes.c_byte),
            ("byte1", ctypes.c_byte),
            ("byte2", ctypes.c_byte),
            ("byte3", ctypes.c_byte),
            ("byte4", ctypes.c_byte),
            ("byte5", ctypes.c_byte),
        ]
    nt_authority = SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY()
    nt_authority.byte5 = 5

    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID = 0x20
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS = 0x220
    administrators_group = ctypes.c_void_p()
    if ctypes.windll.advapi32.AllocateAndInitializeSid(ctypes.byref(nt_authority), 2,
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ctypes.byref(administrators_group)) == 0:
        raise Exception("AllocateAndInitializeSid failed")

    try:
        is_admin = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL()
        if ctypes.windll.advapi32.CheckTokenMembership(
                user_token, administrators_group, ctypes.byref(is_admin)) == 0:
            raise Exception("CheckTokenMembership failed")
        return is_admin.value != 0

    finally:
        ctypes.windll.advapi32.FreeSid(administrators_group)
```

Comment: Quick question however, why does the current_user_is_admin method exist? It doesn't appear to ever be used or called by anything.

Comment: It's just there for a convenience, I think. It shows that the current user's user_token is 0 by default, and gives you the chance (without having to enter the current user's username & password) to step through the function of "Is current user an admin" which might not be possible with ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin().

Answer (score 1):

```
import win32net


def if_user_in_group(group, member):
    members = win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(None, group, 1)
    return member.lower() in list(map(lambda d: d['name'].lower(), members[0])) 


# Function usage
print(if_user_in_group('SOME_GROUP', 'SOME_USER'))
```

Of course in your case 'SOME_GROUP' should be 'administrators'

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to know if a given user has administrator rights (could have domain admin rights, could be in an arbitrary group itself member of local administrator group).
The only way to know for sure is to impersonate the user, but you will need the user's password.
Once you're the user, you can check if you can write into system32 folder (easy way to check whether you're admin... or the FS ACLs are bad lol) or check anything that needs admin powers, like writing an aribtrary registry key into HKLM then delete it.

If you only want to find out if a current user is in local admin group, I've made a package for this, which provides a number of functions among this one

Install with

```
pip install windows_tools.users
```

Usage:

```
import windows_tools.users as users

# if no user is given, current one is used
is_admin = is_user_local_admin('myuser')
print(is_admin)
```

**Longer answer that makes sure a given user has admin rights (still needs the user password)**

My package can impersonate, so you might want to check whether you have full administrator powers by doing the following:

```
pip install windows_tools.impersonate
pip install windows_tools.securityprivilege
```

Example

```
import ctypes
from windows_tools import impersonate
from windows_tools import users
from windows_tools import securityprivilege

with impersonate.ImpersonateWin32Sec(
        domain=".", username='someuser', password='somepassword'
    ):
    print(users.whoami())
    try:
        securityprivilege.enable_privilege("SeSecurityPrivilege")
        securityprivilege.disable_privilege("SeSecurityPrivilege")
        print('Yay, I have admin superpowers')
    except ctypes.WinError:
        print('Nope, I am a simple mortal')
```