# Check multiple users for being admin in windows

Tags: python

I have a list of users and I want to create a python script to check if any of the users has windows admin privileges. I have tried the ctypes lib but apparently it only checks for the current user.

```
import ctypes

lst = ['Administrator','test','Guest']
for i in lst:
     print ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin(i)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass user name to print `ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()` it will just let you know whether logged in user is admin or not

To get whether given user is admin you can refer this [Check if an arbitrary user is in Administrator Group with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773868/check-if-an-arbitrary-user-is-in-administrator-group-with-python)

Comment: thanks I followed ur advice and it works well for me.